# Scala doesn't import from manually created package

Tags: scala, import, package

I'm using Scala with Ubuntu.
There are two files

File a.scala:

```
package ptest { class A() { def p = println ("A") } }
```

File b.scala

```
package ptest { import ptest.A ; class B() { def p = {print("B"); A.p} }
}
```

Compiling b.scala delivers an error:.

```
$ scalac a.scala

$ scalac b.scala

b.scala:2: error: A is not a member of ptest
```

although A.class is stored correct in dictionary ptest.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must explicitly put A.class on the classpath:

```
scalac -classpath . b.scala
```

(Replace `.` with the directory that contains A.class if it isn't in the current directory)

The next issue you have is `import ptest.A`, which doesn't do anything useful and produces a warning. There is no need to import members of the package you are in.

`A.p` produces an error. `A.p` means to invoke `p` on the value `A`, but no value `A` exists at that point. There is a class `A`, but you can't access class members without first creating an instance of that class.